# Convert date into varchar with sas

Tags: sql, sas

I really hope you can assist.

When I run this code:

```
libname odbc ### user='abc' password='****' dsn='bleh' schema='dbo';


%let date=%sysfunc(intnx(day,%sysfunc(today()),-1,b),yymmddd10.);
%put &date.;

run;
```

It works!

But if I run it with the call execute I get this error – it reads from sql – yet the date in sql is varchar:

```
data _null_;
set odbc.SQLTableName;
if ((date= &date.) and (dateComplete ne .))then call execute("%include 'path';"); 

 run;

dateComplete=Jun 10 2015 1:54PM _ERROR_=1 _N_=1
```

I am looking for a way to convert my date.

So it reads `today()-1` (Technically yesterday’s date)

YOUR HELP WILL BE GREATLY APPRECIATED!!!

Comment: Those two bits of code are not sufficiently similar to be comprehensible what you're doing.  What is the %include bit doing?  Is the problem in your call execute (like Haikou suggests) or is it something in your included file?  I have no idea, and can't.

Comment: Hi Joe, like I said to Haikuo, I have never worked on SAS before, what I was trying to do was an 'if statement' that read a date from SQL Server. Something like GETDATE() -1 in SQL, the SAS code needed to read the date in SQL and then execute that the code from the path. The code that it runs will then create a dataset. I will then update a SQL Server table reading how many rows were created in the SAS dataset. My only annoyance is that I am unable to convert the date so that it will read the date from the SQL Server table.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using single quotes instead of double quotes? As you don't want your macro to be executed before the data step ends?

```
call execute("%include 'path';");
```

Try:

```
call execute('%include "path";');
```

Comment: Thank you Haikuo, to be honest I have never worked with SAS before. What I was trying to do was an 'if statement' that read a date from SQL Server. Something like GETDATE() -1 in SQL, the SAS code needed to read the date in SQL and then execute that the code from the path. The code that it runs will then create a dataset. I will then update a SQL Server table reading how many rows were created in the SAS dataset. My only annoyance is that I am unable to convert the date so that it will read the date from the SQL Server table.